# How `pandas.Series.str` works when values are `list`?

Tags: python, pandas, series

How this works? If it's converting each item into string i should get first character like `"[1,2]"[0]` ----> `'['` but instead it treating as `list`, How?

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2],[2,3]]})
>>> df.a.str[0]
0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It working, because `string`s and `list`s are iterables. It means `.str[0]` return first value of string, first value of lists, first value of iterable.

What is `iterable`:

As stated by [Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884501):

> An ITERABLE is:
>
> - anything that can be looped over (i.e. you can loop over a string or file) or
> - anything that can appear on the right-side of a for-loop:   `for x in iterable: ...` or
> - anything you can call with `iter()` that will return an ITERATOR:  `iter(obj)` or
> - an object that defines `__iter__` that returns a fresh ITERATOR,
>   or it may have a `__getitem__` method suitable for indexed lookup.